# Nginx doesn't work try_files in Django app with Vue js

Tags: django, vue.js, nginx

I use history mode in Vue js app on production mode with Django app. So, I have to response all get request by using try_files command on nginx. But it doesn't work. I have tried many docs to solve it, unfortunately, I could not.

My site config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.example.com;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/usr/projects/example;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/usr/projects/example/example.sock
    }
    
    location / {
        root /home/usr/projects/example;
        try_files $uri $uri/templates/index.html $uri.html=404
    }
}
```

Please, help me to find out the error in my code, thanks in advance.

Main urls:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('home.urls')),
    # ... others ursl
]
```

Home urls:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.spa, name='home'),
    # ... others ursl
]
```

index view:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def spa(request):
    return render(request, 'spa/index.html')
```

Comment: you have a typo: `roor /home/usr/projects/example;` should be `root ...`

Comment: @IgorMoraru thanks, I am sorry, I have made a mistake when I was copying.

Comment: Since you have two locations with `/`, only the first one will match. You have to split them by path prefix. Please post your Django urls.py for further guidance

Comment: @AlexandrTatarinov, Sorry for writing not on time, I have added the urls.